# const_cast std::vector

Tags: c++, const-cast

I have a vector with type `const std::vector<const Array*> &objects` which is passed as an argument to the method.

I want to const_cast but I can't do it for some reason. I have tried:

`vector<const Array*> obj = const_cast<const std::vector<const Array*> >(objects);`

and some other ways but it keeps complaining.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, **don't**. Change your function's signature to take a non-const reference, you risk UB by doing this:

```
const std::vector<const Array*> myData = /* fill */;
yourFunction(myData); // try to modify my stuff and you get UB!
```

---

Now if you are still convinced you have to, for whatever reason (like legacy API), it's done like this:

```
vector<const Array*>& obj = const_cast<std::vector<const Array*>&>(objects);
```

Now `obj` and `objects` refer to the same object, but `obj` is not const-qualified. At this point, everything is well-defined; it's only modifying a const *object* that is UB, so be careful.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to pass it to a function which needs to iterate over it (it doesnt to any modification)

Use a `const_iterator`.

You want to cast a `const std::vector<const Array*>` to a `const std::vector<const Array*>`? Aren't they identical. If you want to remove the const:

```
std::vector<const Array*> obj = const_cast<std::vector<const Array*> >(objects);
//                                         |
//                                      no const
```

But a more important question would be: **why**? If `objects` is `const`, you're not supposed to modify it.

Comment: I need to pass it to a function which needs to iterate over it (it doesnt to any modification) but I can't change the api such as marking the function as const

Comment: @Cemre use a `const_iterator` then.

Comment: Well in order to be able to use a const_iterator I will need to modify the API or the function definition, right ?

Comment: @Cemre: If you edited your question to give your motivation for it, people would be able to give you much better answers. Describe the API you're using, the function you want to call, and the overall problem at hand (why you want to call it).

Comment: @Cemre no. You can iterate a const vector with a const iterator.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to cast here, as you are copy constructing the content anyway, and the copy constructor accepts `const` references.

Just say:

```
std::vector<const Array*> obj = objects;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure what you want to do, here is how to obtain a non-const reference to the vector.

```
const std::vector<const Array*> &objects;

vector<const Array*>& obj = const_cast<std::vector<const Array*>& >(objects);
```