# template metafunction for detecting template specialisations

Tags: c++, template-specialization, template-meta-programming, compile-time, static-assert

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14227983/170521), i'm wondering if there is some compile-time check one can introduce to detect if two given template instantiations:

```
template <typename T>
class Templ...

typedef Templ<std::string> stringInstance;
typedef Templ<double> doubleInstance;
```

are constructed from the same definition, or if they are built from different specializations of the `Templ` template

so basically the hypothetical template function will behave like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Templ
{}

template <>
class Templ<std::string>
{}

template <>
class Templ<double>
{}

template <typename T1,typename T2>
class Belong_To_Same_Templ_Definition
{}

//tests
typedef Templ<std::string> stringInstance;
typedef Templ<double> doubleInstance;
typedef Templ<int> intInstance;
typedef Templ<char> charInstance;

assert( Belong_To_Same_Templ_Definition< intInstance , charInstance >::value == true);
assert( Belong_To_Same_Templ_Definition< intInstance , doubleInstance >::value == false);
assert( Belong_To_Same_Templ_Definition< stringInstance , doubleInstance >::value == false);
```

is possible to create this kind of metafunction?

Comment: I like this question, but I'm interested to know what the application(s) of such a facility might be, if it is even possible.

Comment: @Component10, look at the linked question; this would detect when such a cast is safe or not. The cast is safe as long as no specialization exists for a const qualification of the parameter type

Comment: Understood - I can see how this could be useful.

Comment: @lurscher Actually it wouldn't be safe to do so, because the class could contain an instance of another template class which is specialised for `const` types, no?

Comment: I suspect the problem is you are doing relatively simple reasoning about a Turing complete language without taking into account its Turing completeness.  `Belong_To_Same_Templ_Definition` doesn't deduce much of anything useful, given how powerful templates are in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems unlikely, to be honest (although I can't definitively rule out a cunning trick).

There is no first-class identity for a given specialization (outside the type arguments that select it), to compare.

So, you could make it work with your own templates, if you want, but you can't write an ad-hoc inference for existing templates.

Consider also that it *wouldn't work anyway*, in the sense that it couldn't tell whether two instantiations have a compatible layout: even if `Templ<int>` and `Templ<char>` are instantiated from the same template code, with no specialization, that code can use traits classes which *are* specialied.

Comment: so, i'm still trying to figure out a way to make sure my cast is safe... it seems that is not possible using compile-time assertions then

Comment: @lurscher I think it's impossible to make sure the cast is safe for an arbitrary template. You'll have to make a new `vector` and move/copy the elements into it.

Comment: i know, you are probably right, but it feels so wasteful, if only the std:vector would support this with some std::vector<const T>& as_vector_of_consts()

Comment: I agree, but I think the solution is to mix `vector<T>` with `vector<T> const &` (and appropriate const iterators etc.) instead of `vector<T>` and `vector<const T>`