# Declare operator overload for another type in template class definition

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I'm playing around with an `enum_bitmask<E>` template class, where `E` is an enum type, `enum_bitmask<E>` can only be publicly constructed by a default constructor (sets to 0) or from an `E`, and `enum_bitmask<E>` has operator overloads for `|`, `&`, `^`, `~`, and the relevant compound assignment operators. I'd *also* like to define overloads for those operators that take one or two `E`s and return an `enum_bitmask<E>`, but only if `enum_bitmask<E>` has been instantiated elsewhere. Is this possible without macros? Obviously I could do `DECLARE_BITMASK_OPS(E)` and define `DECLARE_BITMASK_OPS` accordingly.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18553843/420683 ; also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553843/how-does-one-use-an-enum-class-as-a-set-of-flags#comment27295220_18553898

Comment: I believe the accepted answer there is broken, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553843/how-does-one-use-an-enum-class-as-a-set-of-flags#comment33264512_18553898

Comment: *"but only if `enum_bitmask<E>` has been instantiated elsewhere"* You can only detect things at compile-time that happen in the same Translation Unit. [Plus, you can't detect instantiation at compile-time.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14244082/420683)